# Условная переменная вместо semaphore

Tags: linux, c

Помогите исправить код, нужно использовать условную переменную вместо semaphore.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class barier
{
private:
    int n;
    int counter;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    sem_t semaphore;


public:
    barier(int threads_number)
    {
        counter = 0;
        n = threads_number;
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
        sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);
    }
void WaitOtherThreads()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    counter++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    while(counter < n)
    {}

    sem_post(&semaphore);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if(counter == n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sem_wait(&semaphore);
        counter = 0;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return;
}
};
void* routine(void* args)
{
    barier* bar = (barier*)args;
    printf("%s\n", "Stage one");

    bar->WaitOtherThreads();

    printf("%s\n", "Stage two");

    bar->WaitOtherThreads();

    printf("%s\n", "Stage three");

    bar->WaitOtherThreads();

    printf("%s\n", "Stage four");

    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int threads_num = 5;

    void* (*p_routine)(void* args) = &routine;

    barier* my_barier = new barier(threads_num);

    pthread_t* tid = new pthread_t[threads_num];

    for(int i = 0; i < threads_num; i++)
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, p_routine, my_barier);

    for(int i = 0; i < threads_num; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

    printf("%s\n", "All threads have been done");

    delete [] tid;
    delete my_barier;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а разве можно переменной заменить механизм семафоров?